# Is there any better way to use string method of pandas to search for multiple strings without regular expression

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Wondering if there is any better solution to search for a string satisfying multiple expressions at the same time without using regular expression in pandas. Already seen other posted answers, most don't point out my concerns.

I have a data_frame containing the cast information of movies, as following shows,

title               actors_list
Toy Story 3  "[u'Tom Hanks', u'Tim Allen', u'Joan Cusack']"
Pulp Fiction  "[u'John Travolta', u'Uma Thurman', u'Samuel L...."

Now I try to select certain movies in which any two given actors have co-starred. For example, I need to find out in what movies did Tom Hanks and Tim Allen cooperate.

```
pat = r'Tom Hanks.*?Tim Allen' 
p = re.compile(pat, flags=re.IGNORECASE)  
d_f[[bool(p.search(x)) for x in d_f['actors_list']]]
```

I solved this problem by using regular expression. It returns entries that with both of the actors appeared in that movie.

Still, I wonder if other elegant ways to achieve this exist.
Many thanks!!!

Comment: Sounds like an ideal use of graphs. However, what format is your dataframe? How did regex solve your issue in this originally etc...?

Comment: @Jon Clements Thank you for your questions, hopefully I answered them after re-edited my post. But I can't understand what do you mean by 'an ideal use of graphs', would you mind going into it a little bit? Thanks again!

Comment: That won't cover if Tim Allen appears before Tom Hanks... so you've got two columns of which one is a text representation of a Python list? How are you loading/getting that data... Because if it's formatted like that it looks like converting them to sets and then perform an intersection will likely be best for what you want...

Comment: @Jon Clements many thanks for you to point out my oversight and your advice is correct. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `pandas.Series.str.contains`.

```
>>> d = pd.DataFrame([{'title':'Toy Story 3 ','actors_list':"[u'Tom Hanks', u'Tim Allen', u'Joan Cusack']"}
                  ,{'title':'Pulp Fiction','actors_list':"[u'John Travolta', u'Uma Thurman', u'Samuel L"}
                  ,{'title':'dummy','actors_list':"[u'Tim Allen', u'Uma Thurman', u'Samuel L"}
                 ])

>>> d[(d.actors_list.str.contains('Tom Hanks'))&(d.actors_list.str.contains('Tim Allen'))]
```

[pandas.str.contains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvENe.png)

Answer (score 0):

As the advice in the comment goes, I convert the 'actors_list' columns into a set, and then I use isubset() to solve this problem.

```
import ast
name_set = {'Tom Hanks', 'Tim Allen'}
df[[name_set.issubset(set(ast.literal_eval(x))) for x in df['actors_list']]]
```